# Node.js http request resulting in CLOSE_WAIT

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I have created a JavaScript program that checks the status of various devices on my network and reports their status to an MQTT server for integration with my home automation dashboard. To check device status I open a connection (either HTTP, HTTPS, or generic TCP.) If the connection succeeds, the device is reported as up. If it fails or times out, it is reported as down. I then end the connection.

This is working well, except for when I connect to the HTTP admin interface for my internet router. With the router, the connection gets stuck in CLOSE_WAIT.

```
netstat -t
tcp    24160      0 uno.home:52544          router.0.168.192.i:http CLOSE_WAIT
tcp    24160      0 uno.home:49742          router.0.168.192.i:http CLOSE_WAIT
tcp    24160      0 uno.home:50820          router.0.168.192.i:http CLOSE_WAIT
tcp    24160      0 uno.home:48084          router.0.168.192.i:http CLOSE_WAIT
...
```

This will go on until I shut down the program or the kernel is no longer able to allocate TCP memory.

I'm running the very same check against an Nginx web server and Portainer (web-based container manager.) Neither of these results in the same CLOSE_WAIT problem. I suspect it's the router that's at fault here, but I'm wondering if there's anything I could change in my code that would help mitigate the problem.

This is the funtion that does the HTTP check:

```
/**
 * Connect to an HTTP server and report the result.
 * @param {string} name  A friendly name given to the service check.
 * @param {string} host  The server's hostname or IP address.
 * @param {number} port  The TCP port number the server listens on.
 * @param {string} path  The directory and file name portion of the URL (e.g. /index.html)
 */
function httpCheck(name, host, port, path) {
  const httpRequest = http.get(`http://${host}:${port}${path}`, (response) => {
    if (debug)
      console.log(`HTTP check for http://${host}:${port}${path} returned: ${response.statusCode}`);
    if (response.statusCode < 400)
      publishStatus(name, config.statusMsg.success);
    else
      publishStatus(name, config.statusMsg.failure);
  });
  httpRequest.on('data', (chunk) => {
    let data = chunk;  // Read and throw away.
  });
  httpRequest.on('close', () => {
    httpRequest.end();
  });
  httpRequest.on('error', (err) => {
    publishStatus(name, config.statusMsg.failure);
    httpRequest.end();
  });
}
```

The `httpRequest.end()` may be redundant. I've added those in an attempt to fix this. I've also added the `.on('data')` thinking the router's web server might be wating for me to read in the whole page before it considers it complete.

I also briefly considered doing just a HEAD request, but the router gives a '501: method not implemented' error.

Again, I find it odd that my checks of Nginx and Portainer are working fine with this code. But, perhaps there is something I'm missing. Is there any possibility to improve the code to avoid the TIME_WAIT?

Comment: Interestingly, if I request a specific resource, like the ISP's logo (`192.168.0.1/images/logo.jpg`) it works as expected and there are no CLOSE_WAITs hanging around. But if I request the root (`192.168.0.1/`) the CLOSE_WAIT problem returns. Using `curl` shows me the page is being delivered when requesting `192.168.0.1/` and not a 301 redirect, so I'm still no closer to uncovering the source of the problem, but I have a workaround.

Comment: CLOSE_WAIT and TIME_WAIT are not the same thing. The [tag:time-wait] tag is therefore irrelevant.